# Summing over months with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I know there is a simple implementation to do this but I cannot remember the syntax.   Have a simple pandas time series and I want to summarize the data by month.   Specifically I want to add data over months and years to get some summary of it.   Can write it with slicing, but I remember seeing syntax that does it automatically.

```
import pandas as pd
df = Series(randn(100), index=pd.date_range('2012-01-01', periods=100))
```

a Multi-indexed Series with Years and sub endexed to months would be first prize.

Partial Answer:

```
ds.resample('M', how=sum)  # for calendar monthly
ds.resample('A', how=sum)  # for calendar yearly
```

Any idea how to elegantly get to multindexed by year sums?

Comment: found answer I think.  added to Question

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
        from numpy.random import randn

In [2]: df = Series(randn(500), index=pd.date_range('2012-01-01', periods=500))

In [3]: s2 = df.groupby([lambda x: x.year, lambda x: x.month]).sum()

In [4]: s2
Out[4]: 
2012  1      3.853775
      2      4.259941
      3      4.629546
      4    -10.812505
      5    -16.383818
      6     -5.255475
      7      5.901344
      8     13.375258
      9      1.758670
      10     6.570200
      11     6.299812
      12     7.237049
2013  1     -1.331835
      2      3.399223
      3      2.011031
      4      7.905396
      5      1.127362
dtype: float64
```

Comment: is there a reason that you are using lamdba instead of using df.index.year and df.index.month (which I would prefer)? Seems to be almost the same in performance.

Comment: they are equivalent, i just used the ``lambda`` to indicate a more dynamic computation e.g. you can do just about anything)