# calculate total events in month using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe using groupby(Code, ID, Date) as shown below -

```
Code    ID  Date              Sum
100 200 2012-05-31   50
                2012-06-07   60
                2012-06-25   70
                2012-06-26   80
                2013-06-27   85
                2013-06-28   90
```

I would like to create a dataframe which can show data with groupby (Code, ID, Month/Year)as -

```
Code    ID     Month/Year     Sum
100     200    May/2012        50
               June/2012       210
               June/2013       175
```

Please advise

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17450313/summing-over-months-with-pandas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a monthly `resample` on each group.

Therefore first convert the 'Date' column to a datetime:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

And then set it as the index, groupby on `['Code', 'ID']` and then apply a `resample` on each group:

```
df.set_index('Date').groupby(['Code', 'ID']).resample('M', 'sum')
```

---

```
In [6]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Code':100, 'ID':200, 'Date':pd.date_range("2012-01-01", periods=10, freq='10D'), 'Sum':np.random.randint(10, size=10)})

In [7]: df
Out[7]:
   Code                Date   ID  Sum
0   100 2012-01-01 00:00:00  200    1
1   100 2012-01-11 00:00:00  200    9
2   100 2012-01-21 00:00:00  200    5
3   100 2012-01-31 00:00:00  200    9
4   100 2012-02-10 00:00:00  200    8
5   100 2012-02-20 00:00:00  200    3
6   100 2012-03-01 00:00:00  200    9
7   100 2012-03-11 00:00:00  200    8
8   100 2012-03-21 00:00:00  200    3
9   100 2012-03-31 00:00:00  200    5

In [8]: df.set_index('Date').groupby(['Code', 'ID']).resample('M', 'sum')
Out[8]:
                     Code   ID  Sum
Code ID  Date
100  200 2012-01-31   400  800   24
         2012-02-29   200  400   11
         2012-03-31   400  800   25
```

---

To plot it, something like this should do it:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for name, group in df.set_index('Date').groupby(['Code', 'ID']):
    group['Sum'].resample('M', 'sum').plot(ax=ax, label=name)
```

But you can also work further with your results, 'unstack' (bring index levels to columns) and then plot:

```
df2 = df.set_index('Date').groupby(['Code', 'ID']).resample('M', 'sum')
df2['Sum'].unstack([0,1]).plot()
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to plot above data  as timeseries chart with x-axis as Date, y-axis as Sum for each ID using matplotlib ?

Comment: And for each Code/ID a seperate line?

Comment: Still facing issue on proposed solution.

Comment: Facing issuer, dataframe (df_final) looks like below - <br>               Code,ID,Date,Code1,Amt1,Code2,Amt2,Code3,Sum
195,10000 - XXX,2012-05-31 00:00:00,40,0.0,180,0.0,780,107970824.0
195,10000 - XXX,2012-06-30 00:00:00,10,0.0,45,0.0,195,8180645.0
195,10000 - XXX,2012-07-31 00:00:00,10,0.0,45,0.0,195,2600000.0
275,30465 - XXX,2012-05-31 00:00:00,10,0.0,45,0.0,275,283905693.0
275,30465 - XXX,2012-06-30 00:00:00,10,0.0,45,0.0,275,75113236.0     and I am ploting as-df_final['Sum'].unstack([0,1]).plot()                  It's throwing error - TypeError: an integer is required

Comment: There was NaN which has been replaced to 0 using fillna('0'). Issue is resolved