# appropriate function for pandas series counting

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I had pandas series which consists of data values for each day. I am trying to count values for each month. 
Below I try something like this, but it is hard coded. Is there any way to make it easy or convert it into function which can operate on pandas series.

```
Jan1 = part_date['date'].str.contains('2010-01').sum()
Feb2 = part_date['date'].str.contains('2010-02').sum()
Mar3 = part_date['date'].str.contains('2010-03').sum()
.
.
.
.
Nov11 = part_date['date'].str.contains('2010-11').sum()
Dec12 = part_date['date'].str.contains('2010-12').sum()



total_months = ['2010-01', '2010-02', '2010-03', '2010-04', '2010-05', '2010-06', '2010-07', '2010-08', '2010-09', '2010-10', '2010-11', '2010-12']
part_months = [Jan1, Feb2, Mar3, Apr4, May5, Jun6, Jul7, Aug8, Sep9, Oct10, Nov11, Dec12,]
plt.scatter(x = total_months, y = part_months)
```

and then i plot the data, but it is hard coding. the data is pandas series and I want to see the frequency of particular date.

e.g the date march month has count of 3000 and April has 5000.

the date column which is pandas series look like this

```
2010-03-19
2010-03-20
2010-03-20
.
.
.
2010-03-21
.
.  
.
2010-04-15
2010-04-16
```

I am trying to plot the frequency of date columns for each month. 
Is there any way to convert it to function or other method so that I can use it.

Comment: `pd.Series([Jan1, Feb2, Mar3, Apr4, May5, Jun6, Jul7, Aug8, Sep9, Oct10, Nov11, Dec12],index=total_months)` then plot

Comment: Convert `date` column to date with [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17450313/summing-over-months-with-pandas).

Comment: @Wen I follow piSquare answer and it solve my problem, but is there any way to plot now this as scatter plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's data, and assuming we've already converted to datetimes...

We can use `set_axis` and `resample`

```
v.set_axis(v.values, inplace=False).resample('M').count()

2010-01-31    3
2010-02-28    3
2010-03-31    3
2010-04-30    3
2010-05-31    3
2010-06-30    3
2010-07-31    3
2010-08-31    3
2010-09-30    3
2010-10-31    3
2010-11-30    3
2010-12-31    3
Freq: M, dtype: int64
```

---

**Response to Comments**

> is there any way to plot this data as scatter plot instead of line plot. thanks – Rio

I don't think you want a scatter plot.  Scatter plots require that the axes be numeric.  Your index is a datetime value.  If you insist, you can force the datetime as an integer.  But in my opinion, this is clumsy and ugly.

```
new = v.set_axis(v.values, inplace=False).resample('M').count()
new = new.rename_axis('Date').reset_index(name='Count')
new.Date = new.Date.astype(int)
new.plot.scatter(x='Date', y = 'Count')
```

[image]

Otherwise, use a line plot and set the marker

```
v.set_axis(v.values, inplace=False).resample('M').count().plot(lw=0, marker='o')
```

[image]

Comment: is there any way to plot this data as scatter plot instead of line plot. thanks

Comment: thanks a lot for your kind help. I tried a lot to plot scatter plot but I was unable to do correctly.  I wish I had coding skills like you.  yes line plot and marker do a perfect job for me.

Comment: Thank you for the compliment and glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

```
# convert your column to `datetime`
v = pd.to_datetime(part_date['date'], errors='coerce')
# filter out all rows that do not belong to readings in 2010
v = v[v.dt.year == 2010]
# convert v to a string column using strftime and call `value_counts`
v.dt.strftime('%Y-%m').value_counts().sort_index()
```

The last line of code produces a result you can call `.plot` on directly.

---

**Demo**

```
v = pd.Series(pd.date_range('2000-01-01', '2017-12-31', freq='10D'))
v = v[v.dt.year == 2010]

v.head()

366   2010-01-08
367   2010-01-18
368   2010-01-28
369   2010-02-07
370   2010-02-17
dtype: datetime64[ns]

v.dt.strftime('%Y-%m').value_counts().sort_index()

2010-01    3
2010-02    3
2010-03    3
2010-04    3
2010-05    3
2010-06    3
2010-07    3
2010-08    3
2010-09    3
2010-10    3
2010-11    3
2010-12    3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: @COLDSPEED Actually I had data of multiple years. I tried to run your code but it gives me days of each month.

Comment: @Rio You should've run `v = v[v.dt.year == 2010]` as well which would've fixed that.

Comment: @COLDSPEED I run the above commands accordingly but it gives me me the same months date. i run these commands.   v = pd.to_datetime(part_date['date'], errors='coerce')  v = v[v.dt.year == 2010]   v.dt.strftime('%Y-%m').value_counts().sort_index() . .. .

Comment: @COLDSPEED Can I accept the answer of piSquared because that works fine. .

Comment: @Rio Yes, please do, I would be more than happy if you did.